# Getting an error while running a simple code on C : __GI_rewind (fp=0x0) at ./libio/rewind.c: ./libio/rewind.c: No file with such name

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I am trying to execute this code which is supposed to read a file with char in order to store them in a double table of char variable. Here is the content of the file:
###############################################dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd##dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd###############################################
The output stops printing after the last execution of the second loop. The last output in the terminal is the last line of the file ending by 319 which is the value of the i variable.

It seems like the problem happens at the end of the loop. There does not seem to be any problems with the reading of the file but rather with the exiting of the loop.    According to the error message, it seems like it is a problem with the libraries. This is why, i have tried uninstalling all my C libraries and reinstalled them but it did not resolve the problem.  I used printf() to try and debug and I have found that the problem occurs when exiting the loop. The last output is i=319.  I am out of potential solutions as I do not understand the error message.

I am running the gcc 11.4.0 version

Here is the code:

```
#define LOADMAP_H
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>


const int mX=46;
const int mY=32;
float square_size_width=3;
float square_size_height=3;
char **map;
void loadmap()
//fonction qui ouvre le fichier txt et charge la carte dans le tableau
{
    map = malloc(sizeof(char *) * mY);  
    FILE *f = NULL;
    f = fopen("map1.txt", "r");
    if(f == NULL)
    {
        printf("file empty");
    }
    char c;
    int i=0;
    int j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < mY; i++)
    {
        *(map + i) = malloc(sizeof(char *) * mX);   
        for(j = 0; j < mX; j++)
        {       
            c = fgetc(f);
            map[i][j] = c;
            printf("%c", map[i][j]);
        }
        printf("%i\n",i);
    }
    fclose(f);

}
```

Comment: How do you compile this? Can you provide a [mcve], too?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgdb%5D+doesn%27t+find+source+file -- does that explain your problem perhaps?

Comment: I have added an answer in order to be more complete. The link shared does not seem to treat the same problem

Comment: Even taking the misplaced answer into account ([edit] your Q instead), this is still far from a [mcve]. Think about e.g. wildcards, which are impossible to interpret without context.